# Putty or Tera Term VT alternative for OS X

Tags: macos, putty, serial-port

I am currently using putty and Tera Term VT for connecting to external devices over serial port for bugging. Is there any alternative for OS X?

Comment: MAC is a commonly used networking term, short for "Media Access Control". Perhaps you mean "Mac"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions available.

My preference is the [ZOC Terminal Emulator](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html).

It is commercial, but also available for Windows and MacOS also.  It does serial connections, also SSH and Telnet, rsh ... quite like Putty.

[image: screenshot of ZOC]

Other serial alternatives for the Mac would be zTerm and iTerm.

Answer (score 3):

The best aqua app I've seen is [CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org/).  You can also do it with [minicom](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041026113304907) or [screen](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20061109133825654).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with serial ports, but you should be able use the built in Terminal app which is provided by Apple (search for it with spotlight).

It's a very good terminal client, my personal favourite by far on any platform.

You need to use the `screen` command inside Terminal, but beyond that I'm not sure how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

### Mini tutorial for `screen`

`screen` is a command line app and distributed with macOS.  You can use it in a Terminal window.  Typical usage:

- Launch Terminal.app
- Using the command line, find the serial port for your device, e.g. `ls /dev/cu*`
- Also using the command line, launch `screen`, e.g. `screen /dev/cu.usbserial-DN06C8VG 115200`

Of course, substitute in the correct serial device and baud rate for your needs.  And to get out:

- `^a^\` (that's Control-A Control-backslash)

Comment: Thank you! best solution without any external software :)

Answer (score 0):

There is picocom. A quick google found binary for 10.6

Comment: Please consider adding more information, e.g. where you found this.